# Why a dynamic type using TypeBuilder cannot be shown in Watch window?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection.emit, typebuilder

I have created a dynamic Type using TypeBuilder like bellow:

```
var assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("TestDynamicAsm"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("DynamicModule");

TypeBuilder tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType("TestType", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class
                                                      | TypeAttributes.AutoClass | TypeAttributes.AnsiClass
                                                      | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit | TypeAttributes.AutoLayout, null);
tb.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);
tb.DefineField("Comment", typeof(string), FieldAttributes.Public);

var type = tb.CreateType();

// test to ensure dynamic type field is created
object test = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

/* Here is the issue...
 * Why cant I add the test in watch and/or quick window?
 * 
 */ 

// This is a test to show the type is fine!
dynamic d = test;
// we can set the field
d.Comment = "here we go... a sample comment!";
// we can read the field
var result = d.Comment;
```

Which it creates a type like this:
    class TestType
    {
        public string Comment;
    }

I am able to create an instance of the type using Activator and assign the value to Comment field.

My issue is when I try to check the instance of the dynamic type in the Visual Studio's Watch widow it get an error: "Could not evaluate expression".

[image]

Why is that and how can I fix this?

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. Your code compiles without an error in VS2015 FW4/4.5 and i am able to inspect all variables in the local window as well as in the watch window.